# Display tabbed form on database open

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an access database with some queries, tables and form. Is there an option which would display only the form when anyone opens the database?

So when I open a database I want to see the form Open (Tabbed) and no other objects, basically hide the navigation pane.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set various start up options. It is probably best to build a run-time solution, if you wish to deploy your application.

[Basics for Building Access 2007 Runtime-Based Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136539%28office.12%29.aspx)

Which contains:

[Setting Startup Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136539%28office.12%29.aspx#Access2007BuildingRuntimeBasedSolutions_SettingStartupOptions)

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you un-checked the display navigation pane option.

In fact, you might even want to disable document tables.

The one line of code you need in the startup form is this:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

And when you do the above, you get this effect:

[image]

Note how in above none of the Access interface shows.

In the above I did un-check the "display" docuemnt tabs and that even removed the bar above the form.

So, really this is only one line of VBA code, the rest is choosing to not display the navigation pane and un-check tabs options etc in the "options" area of Access.

Just remember for development, you have to hold down shift key during startup else you not be able to change/work on anything!

To disable options like right click "design" from users, then you want to deploy a compiled accDE to your users since this strips out source code and removes the ability of users to modify forms and reports and any of your VBA code. However once again, you can un-check the options for speical keys etc. in the options area, but for the most part, it makes sense to deploy a accDE and not your accDB to users.

Albert D. Kallal  (Access MVP)

Edmonton, Alberta Canada